# SQL query to calculate the OS Type and OS Language (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I did research and could not find any query to calculate the OS Type and OS Language. Can anyone help me with the same

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT windows_release, windows_service_pack_level, windows_sku, os_language_version  
FROM sys.dm_os_windows_info;
```

From SQL Server 2017

```
SELECT host_platform, host_distribution, host_release, 
    host_service_pack_level, host_sku, os_language_version  
FROM sys.dm_os_host_info;
```

Comment: Is the Column windows_sku same as OS type?

Comment: No, Its Windows Stock Keeping Unit.  Find more details at 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-windows-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: What information you are exactly looking.  OS version installed?

Comment: Providing sample data you are expecting will be much helpful to give the right answer